# Camunda BMPN Synchronous Response using Camunda REST API

Tags: java, rest, bpmn, camunda

Is it possible to get synchronous response from Camunda BPMN flow Using Camunda REST API?

For example I have 2 service tasks,

`1. Validate Address`,

`2. Get ProductList`.

Now i am starting the process with REST API provided by the Camunda(*Not using Cockpit to start the process*). Address Validation service task is executed, ProductList task is executed successfully and response of it `i.e. List of products`, will be returned in the response of calling Client instead of digging into camunda with process id. I Searched it, but haven't found any such example or lead to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the REST documentation, there is no other way to get Actual response (i.e `List of Product`) from the REST API as the return type of the rest call as the return type is in following format -

```json
    {
      id: "95aef406-3a7a-11e5-85b6-dafa20524153",
      definitionId: "invoice:1:15e97a1c-312d-11e5-aca3-a0e120524153",
      businessKey: null,
      caseInstanceId: null,
      ended: true,
      suspended: false
    }
```

It shows that process is ended(`ended: true`) as all the call's were synchronous, [Camunda Rest Create Process](https://blog.camunda.org/post/2015/08/start-and-complete-process-with-rest-api/)

Now if user wants to read the parameter from the process, then needs to call the history service as the process was synchronous and ended.

`GET /history/variable-instance`, See
[Process History Variables](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/rest/history/variable-instance/get-variable-instance-query/) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way doing this with just the rest api, and even with an embedded process engine doing this without additional queries and process variables is a bit tricky.

One way to solve this is to introduce a "context" object, which is either managed by a dependency injection framework or as a simple `ThreadLocal`. This context would contain both input and output parameters and can be accessed when starting the process and from the service tasks.

```
class Context {
    private String address;
    private List<String> products;

    public Context(String address) { this.address = address; }

    public String getAddress() { return address; }

    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }

    public List<String> getProducts() { return products; }

    public void setProducts(List<String> products) { this.products = products; }
}

class CurrentContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<Context> value = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(Context context) {
        value.set(context);
    }

    public static Context get() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public static void remove() {
        value.remove();
    }
}

class GetProductList implements JavaDelegate {
    @Override
    public void execute(final DelegateExecution execution) {
        final Context context = CurrentContext.get();
        context.setProducts(getProducts(context.getAddress()));
    }
}
```

Before starting the process using the java api you would initialize the context, and afterwards retrieve the results from the context:

```
final Context context = new Context("address");
CurrentContext.set(context);
try {

    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(...);

    return context.getProducts();
} finally {
    CurrentContext.remove();
}
```

We are using this pattern (with the context managed by a custom spring scope) quite successfully.

Comment: Where the last code snippet go. I am just beginner and have learn on REST part and exploring other area.

Comment: @Swaraj Sorry, I missed the requirement about using the rest api only, the example above is using the java api of an embedded process engine.

Comment: Thanks, this is going to help while dealing with Camunda API. But one thing i learned is, one cannot get actual response from the REST API, instead has to use processInstanceID/Business Key to get more details from Process Instance using REST API.

Comment: Get the records persisted to H2 DB in Camunda
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66667221/11152084?sem=2

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, a process should always be seen as something that can be processed asynchronous. For that reason, I'd check for alternatives instead of trying to get a result directly from the process start.

One common approach would be that your application offers a web endpoint (e.g. a HTTP GET endpoint) which acts as callback handler. The Camunda process can notify your endpoint (with some identifier of your data as part of the callback, and the result) just before the service process gets completed.